# djStripe subscriber_has_active_subscription is always false

Tags: django, stripe-payments

On the current djStripe configuration say:

> Customer User Model has_active_subscription property
>
> Very useful for working inside of templates or other places where you
>   need to check the subscription status repeatedly. The cached_property
>   decorator caches the result of has_active_subscription for a object
>   instance, optimizing it for reuse.

And ask you to add this code:

```
@cached_property
def has_active_subscription(self):
    """Checks if a user has an active subscription."""
    return subscriber_has_active_subscription(self)
```

But for me the answer is always false

What's happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After review the code of djStripe I came with 2 solutions, you can read there:

```
def user_has_active_subscription(user):
    warnings.warn("Deprecated - Use ``subscriber_has_active_subscription`` instead. This method will be removed in dj-stripe 1.0.", DeprecationWarning)
    return subscriber_has_active_subscription(user)
```

Then you must use this instead:

```
@cached_property
def has_active_subscription(self):
    """Checks if a user has an active subscription."""
    return user_has_active_subscription(self)
```

But that still don't work for me, when I still reading I found this warning:

> Helper function to check if a subscriber has an active subscription.
>       Throws improperlyConfigured if the subscriber is an instance of AUTH_USER_MODEL
>       and get_user_model().is_anonymous == True.

My problem was exactly that, I was calling this function from my profile, then this fix it:

```
@cached_property
def has_active_subscription(self):
    """Checks if a user has an active subscription."""
    return user_has_active_subscription(self.user)
```

---

UPDATE: My mistake is a problem with my current system, you can read more here: https://github.com/pydanny/dj-stripe/issues/203#issuecomment-110230688